# Why Can't These Linear Equations Be Solved?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following three linear equations:

$$s_1 = k^{-1}(h_1 + rx_1)$$
$$s_2 = k^{-1}(h_2 + rx_2)$$
$$s_3 = k^{-1}(h_3 + rx_3)$$

I have the values of following parameters:

- $s_n$ (different for each equation but known)
- $h_n$ (different for each equation but known)
- $r$ (the same across all equations)

I do not have the value of the following parameters:

- $k$ (the same across all equations)
- $x_n$ (different for each equation)

I know that $k$ and $r$ are equal across all of the equations, but I do not know the value of $k$.

**Is it possible to calculate $k$ or $x_n$?  If not, why not?** Can the equality of $k$ across the equations provide help in solving the equations?

Note: I asked a related question the other day about using Gaussian elimination to solve three linear equations but did not manage to obtain an answer.  I've posted this separately to attempt to understand *why* it can't be solved.

Comment: You have more unknowns than equations so the system is underdetermined. You will be able to find (for example) the $x_i$'s in terms of the value of $k$.

Comment: You have three equations and 4 unknowns. That means you cannot obtain specific values in principle.

Comment: Thank you for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't determine the four unknown $k,\,x_j$ from these three equations. But if $r\ne0$ then since $x_j=(ks_j-h_j)/r$, if we knew $k$ we could determine the $x_j$. Construed as the vector equation $x=(ks-h)/r$, the solution set is a line in $x$-space, on which each point has a different value of $k$.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfectly explained in plain language