# Solving Equation With Two Equal Unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048850/why-cant-these-linear-equations-be-solved/), I asked why it was not possible to solve the following three linear equations for $x_n$ when I knew the values of $s$, $h$, $r$ and knew that $k$ was the same for all three but did not have the value:

$$s_1 = k^{-1}(h_1 + rx_1)$$
$$s_2 = k^{-1}(h_2 + rx_2)$$
$$s_3 = k^{-1}(h_3 + rx_3)$$

The answer was that there are 4 unknowns and three equations, despite knowing that the unknown $k$ was the same across all three.

I have a follow up question now regarding the following equation:

$$s = k^{-1}(h + rx)$$

If I know $s$, $h$ and $r$, and I know that $k = x$ (but don't know either of their values), can this be solved?

Comment: Yes. $sx = h+rx \leadsto x = h/(s-r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$s = k^{-1}(h + rx);\;k=x$$
$$s=\frac{h+rx}{x}$$
$$sx=h+rx$$
$$sx-rx=h\to x(s-r)=h$$
$$x=\frac{h}{s-r}$$